# Compare two ranges: classic range vs range of comma-delimited values in a single cell

Tags: excel, vba, udf

Suppose I've got a range of values:
6   2   4   7   8   7
1   5   1   9   4   6
8   8   1   7   4   2

And separately in a single cell: 
"1, 4, 9"

I need to compare these values in a single cell with the given range. In case if there is a match - type "Yes", if not - "No".

"1, 4, 9" -  result: "Yes"

"3, 10, 11" - result: "No"

Here I've got a UDF that simply compares two ordinary ranges and enters number of times values were matched as a result. Should work as a kind of a template I suppose.

```
 Public Function Compare(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As Long
   Dim r As Range, v As Variant, v2 As Variant
   Dim rr As Range
   For Each r In r1
      v = r.Value
      If v <> 0 And v <> "" Then
         For Each rr In r2
            v2 = rr.Value
            If v = v2 Then Compare = Compare + 1
         Next rr
      End If
   Next r
End Function
```

Comment: One match returns "yes", or all the numbers must have a match to get "yes"?

Comment: At least one match for "yes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified the code to split the first cell range:

```
 Public Function Compare(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As Long
   Dim r As Integer, v As Variant, v2 As Variant
   Dim rr1() As String
   Dim rr As Range
   rr1 = Split(r1, ",")
   For r = LBound(rr1) To UBound(rr1)
      v = --Trim(rr1(r))
      If v <> 0 And v <> "" Then
         For Each rr In r2
            v2 = rr.Value
            If v = v2 Then Compare = Compare + 1
         Next rr
      End If
   Next r
End Function
```

To get the "Yes/No" you would call it like this:

```
=IF(Compare(A1,$D$1:$D$18)>0,"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much mate!